# Webpack.config alias resolves during build but not during page load

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm new to webpack and trying to work with some of the scaffoldings out there.

I'm trying to add an alias to the webpack config.

`resolve: {
    alias: {
      '_utils': path.join(PATH_SRC, '/utils'),
    },
  }`

It resolves fine during the build:
`./src/utils/debounce.js`

But the alias path doesn't get resolved when I try to load the page in the browser.

I feel like I must be missing something basic...  Do I maybe need to pass these settings through to the hot-loader or something?

Here's the error I get

`GET / 500 238.910 ms - 882
Error: Cannot find module '_utils/debounce'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.../src/www/routes/RootRoute/CodeRoute/Component.js:23:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at loader (/.../node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:127:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/.../node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:137:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)`

There is a demo repo here:
https://github.com/erchaves/example-app/tree/config-resolve-alias-example
(use `npm run dev`)

With notes in this commit:
https://github.com/erchaves/example-app/commit/3486b230a3188df19fcdcbb8f9401d2b4b8400e9

Thanks!